# Is there any way to shape an input text box like pyramid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

How to shape a input text box like a pyramid?
Please see the image at

[image]

I want to make a contact form like as this image. 
Please let me know how i can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try yet? If you don't want to use an background image, you could just clip the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your contact form as displayed in the image. you have to be little tricky.
Please see the image below.
The highlighted part indicates the Size of your text-box. Rest is the CSS in your background and similar CSS for text box is applied so that it looks merged with the background CSS.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Best thing that comes to my mind is that you can use this pyramid as a background of a div. Then place text boxes on that div. Style them to look like on the image,
        .textbox{
          background-color:transparent;
          border:none;
          color:white
        }
is a example. You can use different width for different text boxes to get the desired look.